# Android Edit Text not visible while keyboard is on

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

[image: Footer included layout moves up when keyboard is visible]

*layout.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.LaunchActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header_relative_layout"
            layout="@layout/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/body_relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linear_layout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_relative_layout"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/footer_linear_layout"
            layout="@layout/footer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to move whole layout up when keyboard is visible but,
only footer layout (Included layout) moves up.
Behind the keyboard there are two more edit text and one button.

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" is added in manifest activity.

In android:id="@+id/body_relative_layout" I've added layout programatically with layoutInflater.

```
 bodyRelativeLayout.removeAllViews();
  bodyRelativeLayout.addView(bodyView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NestedScrollView` for scrolling up whole layout like below:

```
<RelativeLayout><!--Main Layout-->
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
   <!--Layout code for edittext-->
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout> 
<! You can directly use include tag here-->
<!--bottom view that will scroll up when keyboard show-->
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/rlMainLayout">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer_linear_layout">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <include
                            android:id="@+id/header_relative_layout"
                            layout="@layout/header_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/body_relative_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/header_relative_layout"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/footer_linear_layout"
            layout="@layout/footer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Manifest file:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize`